# I do not understand how the 2nd loop has O(i^2)?

Tags: time-complexity

> the second loop runs from i to i^2 -1 so no. of times = i^2 - i + 1

```
function(int n) {
```

> outer runs n times

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < i * i; j++) {
            if (j % i == 0) {
```

> this runs j times

```
                for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                    printf("*");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so no. of times = i^2 - i + 1

If `i` becomes **larger**, for example extremely large, then both `i^2` amd `i` are both becoming extremely large. However, `i^2` is increasing 
*faster* than `i`, then the increase of `i` can be *ignored* compared to the increase of `i^2`. For the [Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), this is expressed as **O(i^2)**.

Besides, it is "O" (letter O), not "0" (number zero).

Answer (score 0):

You will find your answer here

```
for (int j = i; j < i * i; j++) {
```

j is running to i^2 (or i * i), which results in O(i^2) for the inner loop

Comment: the starting point can be ignored when i gets bigger, just as an example, take i=100... so j will run from 100 to 100.000 which means 99.900 iterations which is almost at i*i.

Answer (score 0):

What you say is that because the inner loop goes from i to i², complexity must not be O(i²).
The complexity is indeed **at most** O(i²) but:

1. **For i = 1**, the 2nd loop is executed 1 time
2. **For i = 10**, 90 times (not too far from 100)
3. **For i = 100**, 9900 times (not too far from 10000)
4. **For i = 1000**, 999000 times (not too far from 1M)

Every time you multiply i by a number n (10 in my case), the inner loop will run for just more than n² more times.
That shows the complexity is **at least** O(i²).

Conclusion: the complexity is **exactly** (= at most + at least) O(i²)

---

**General knowledge about complexity:**

Most of the code you will ever see has a complexity within the below ordered list, or a combination of them (more about that later):
`n^0 (= constant) < log2(n) < sqrt(n) < n < n^2 < exp(n)`

Complexity is a term that only applies for very big numbers.
It is irrelevant for small values, as you will see [here](https://woboq.com/blog/qmap_qhash_benchmark.html) for example.

In your case, with a very big value, `i²` is overwhelming in front of `i` so `O(i²-i) = O(i²)`.

More generally speaking, complexity only multiplies:

- Your outer loop is `O(n)`
- Your inner loop is `O(n^2)`
- Result: your code sample is `O(n^3)`

Obviously, when you combine complexities, the order will stay unchanged.
For instance, my ordered list before, multiplied by `O(n)` will become:
`n < n*log2(n) < n*sqrt(n) < n^2 < n^3 < n*exp(n)`

As you can see, thanks to  were values between n and n^2 in my previous list.